# Why is my vector's magnitude more accurate when I use a variable?

Tags: java, vector, floating-point, processing, precision

I'm writing a program in Processing where I normalize a vector into a unit vector. 
When I do that,I expect my vector to have a magnitude of 1. However, my vector's magnitude is this (see below)

[image: mistake]

The magnitude is close to 1 but it's not *exactly* 1. I figured out that I could get the vector's magnitude to 1 if I declared a variable that equals the vector's magnitude and  divided my vector's components by the variable *instead* of the vector's magnitude directly, like below.

[image: solution]

Any idea why my vector's magnitude is more accurate when I use a variable? 
`mag` equals `mag()`, `mag` is a float while `mag()` returns a float so I don't understand why I'm getting a difference in magnitudes.

My entire code is below.

```
PVector center, mouse; 

void setup() {
  size(1000,300);
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  center = new PVector(width/2,height/2);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  mouse = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
  mouse.sub(center); //Mouse is now the vector between mouse and center. 
  mouse.normalize();
  println("magnitude: " + mouse.mag() + 
          ", Vector coordinates: (" + mouse.xPos + "," + mouse.yPos + ")" );
  /* These values are getting normalized already, so the magnitude of the 
  vectors should be equal to 1. 
  */
  translate(center.xPos, center.yPos);
  line(0,0,mouse.xPos,mouse.yPos); 
}

class PVector { 
  float xPos; // xPos and yPos are the vector's components.
  float yPos;

  PVector (float xTemp, float yTemp) {
    xPos = xTemp;
    yPos = yTemp;
  }

  void sub(PVector vectorTemp) {
    xPos = xPos - vectorTemp.xPos; 
    yPos = yPos - vectorTemp.yPos;
  }

  float mag() {
    float magnitude = sqrt(xPos * xPos + yPos * yPos);
    return magnitude; 
  }

  void normalize() {
    float mag = mag(); // My vector's magnitude is 1 when I use a variable.
    xPos =  xPos/mag;
    yPos =  yPos/mag;

  }
}
```

Comment: Think about what `mag()` will return **after** you update `xPos`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first (imprecise) version has one flaw:
It updates `xPos` and **afterwards** calculates `mag()` with the updated `xPos`. Which means `yPos` is scaled relative to an entirely different vertex.

E.g. a sample flow of that method for a vector `(3, 4)` would look like this:

```
xPos = 3
yPos = 4

mag() = sqrt(3^2 + 4^2) = 5
xPos = 3 / 5

mag() = sqrt(3^2/5^2 + 4^2) ~= 4.045
yPos = 4 / ~4.045
```

which leads to an overall magnitude of ~1,2605 in the above example.

The other version on the other hand correctly first calculates the magnitude and afterwards updates the position-values.